# How can I get a section of a string?

Tags: java, directory, substring, parent

I'm trying to return the directories of a file/directory and also their directories.

I have for example `"this/iss/the/root/assets/images/icons/parent"` which is the parent of `"this/iss/the/root/assets/images/icons/parent/child`.

This will be the root path `this/iss/the/root` and I want to get everything after the root path: `assets/images/icons/examples'` i.e. given the root, how can I extract all the directories after the root but before the child?

I have tried:

```
parent.lastIndexOf(root)
```

but it gives me the entire parent path.

Sorry this was very long winded. I've spent ages staring at my code none stop and it's nearly midnight!

Comment: Java strings can be split into parts using regex. Have you tried that?

Comment: Also, lastIndexOf takes a character, not a string, and returns an int, not a string, so I'm not sure what you're talking about there.

Comment: I think http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29 is what you're looking for.

Comment: Why someone downvoted on this ?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, @Vash...

Comment: So anyone care to explain why it was downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    String str = "this/iss/the/root/assets/images/icons/parent/child";
    String root = "this/iss/the/root/";
    String rootRegex = root.replace("/", "\\/"); //escape fwd slashes
    String ptrnStr = "^" + rootRegex + "(.+)child\\Z";
    java.util.regex.Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(ptrnStr); 

    java.util.regex.Matcher mtchr = ptrn.matcher(str);

    if(mtchr.find())
    {
        String between = mtchr.group(1);
        System.out.println("FOUND:  " + between);
    }
```

Comment: +1 for Regex, -1 for complex. btw as you decided yo to use replace you could call on str and replace root with "" and /child with "".

Comment: but what if the inside of the string, between the root and the child, contained a substruing that was syntatically the same as either the root or the child?  it would get replaced

Comment: e.g. what is the path was this /root/subdir1/subdir2/root/subdir4/child ?  you would have to specify that you are replacing the root and the child specifically from the start and the end of the string and not any match in between

Comment: That why i would not use anything that replace but get string from index x to index y. where x is root.len and y is src.len - child.len. ;-).

Answer (score 0):

One way could be like this, combining [`#lastIndexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29) with [`#substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29):

```
String parent = "this/iss/the/root/assets/images/icons/parent";
if (parent.lastIndexOf("root/") != -1) {
    child = parent.substring(parent.lastIndexOf("root/") + 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recomend you to use the [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) class from Java 7.

You just call `path.getParent()` or call `iterator()` and work until you reach your destination.

Comment: So, you are doing it wrong. Post the code that you are working on. This will for sure help. Or accept a answer that, worked for you.